# Configure the viewport settings of a website opened in iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am opening a website in iFrame of custom height and width(300 x 400). Media queries of that website is not working because of having `max-device-width` used for changing the css. Also, for that iframe even `screen.availWidth`(coming as 1240px) is same desktop width instead of iframe width. 
While doing same with Chrome emulation for custom devices(iPhone 5), I can see screen.availWidth(to be 320px) and `max-device-width` to be working. Any solution for this so that I can change the `screen.width` values for website opened in iFrames?

Comment: Just because you put something in an iframe, doesn’t mean your actual screen suddenly becomes smaller ...

Comment: I want to mock screen size for that website opened within iframe not for the top window.

Comment: Then you will probably have to write a browser extension to manipulate those values; normal JS in a website context won’t get you far, at least if both sites are from different domains. // A website using screen.availWidth for responsibility purposes is rather doing something wrong to begin with. The browser window does not have to be as big as the screen, so basing any decisions on that is rather nonsense.

Comment: The website is not using `screen.availWidth`, it is using media queries and in that it is using `max-device-width` which does not work when opened in custom size iframe. My only question is that any way I can see the responsive website in iframe and `max-device-width` take value from iframe width instead of screen resolution width.

Comment: That is not possible. The device width does also not change, just because you put something into an iframe.

Comment: So, is there any alternative of this? How can we implement this with Chrome extension.